# Cassandra data modelling - Select subset of rows in large table for batch Spark processing

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I am working on a project in which we ingest large volumes of structured raw data into a Cassandra table and then transform it to a target schema using Spark.

Since our raw data table is getting pretty large we would like to process it in batches. That means Spark has to look at our raw data table to identify not yet processed rows (by partition key) and then load the subset of these rows into Spark.

Being new to Cassandra I am now wondering how to implement this. Using Spark, I can quite efficiently load raw data keys and compare them with the keys in the transformed table to identify the subsets. But what is the best strategy to load the subset of these rows from my raw data table.

Here is an example. If my schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE raw_data (
    dataset_id text PRIMARY KEY,
    some_json_data text
);
```

...and if I have dataset_ids 1,2,3,4,5 in my table and know that I now need to process the rows with ids 4, 5, how can I efficiently select those rows knowing that the list of ids can be pretty long in practice?

Comment: Is there any common field of your dataset_ids  which you are selecting at the same time ?

Comment: dataset_id is actually hash; so no, there is no common field...

Comment: I am trying to to say, is there any specific condition by which you are selecting dataset_ids

Comment: have you looked at the joinWithCassandraTable method?